# react-intl, async translation import and SSR

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering, react-intl

I have a React app which uses `react-intl` to provide translations and it's working fine for browser DOM rendering. I have a component which deals with async locale/translation based on props it receives, using `import()` and then once locale + translation data are loaded, `<IntlProvieder>` is rendered. Like so:

```
// constructor

import(`react-intl/locale-data/${langCode}`).then((localeData) => {
  addLocaleData(localeData.
  this.setState({localeDataLoaded: true});
});

import(`../../translations/${locale}.json`).then((translations) => {
  this.setState({translations: translations.default});
});
```

```
render() {
  if (!this.state.translations || !this.state.localeDataLoaded) {
    return null;
  }

  return (
    <IntlProvider locale={this.props.locale} messages={this.state.translations} >
      {this.props.children}
    </IntlProvider>
  );
}
```

However, when it comes to SSR, the `setState()` calls don't trigger `render()` thus blocking the rest of the app from rendering.

I'd like to know what others are doing with regards to i18n and server/DOM rendering. Ideally I'm not going to be sending extraneous locale data to users over the web and I'd like a single component to manage all of this for both renderers.

Alternatively I may end up baking translations into the output file and generating JS files per locale

Comment: Currently your code has syntax errors and is incomplete. Could you update your question?

Comment: Please treat it as pseudo code. I'm more interested in approach than exact code

Answer (score 0):

For SSR you'd have to load things before rendering in the request lifecycle, then pass those down to react-intl